# How do I make project modifications to store Asp .net Core Angurlar 6 bundle in CDN

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

How do like to store the following files in CDN. This line gets created in index.html when the project is built. Where do I make modifications in the project so that after a built these files points to CDN urls.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.991eda935898a57f5c1f.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.92795880e21717c67f9d.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.216ced67f3811f0ff7ea.js"></script>
```

Comment: What CDN?  Akamai?  Limelight? AWS? ________________?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `deploy-url` while building your angular project - so that your files will be pointing to the mentioned CDN url

Try something like this

`ng build --prod --deploy-url=yourUrl`

After running this command check your `index.html`

Hope this helps - happy coding :)